# Is $A(D)$ a complemented subspace of $C(T)$?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $T$ be the unit circle and $D$ the open unit disk. A function $f$ belongs to $C(T)$ if it is continuous at $T$. A function $g$ belongs to $A(D)$ if it is continuous at $\overline{D}$ and holomorphic on $D$. Thus $A(D)|_{T}\subset C(T)$.
Now, if we think of the symmetric partial sums of the Fourier series of $f\in C(T)$, we notice that
$$\sum_{k=-n}^n a_k(f)e^{ikt}=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k(f)e^{ikt}+\sum_{k=-n}^{-1} a_k(f)e^{ikt}=g_{n}(e^{it})+h_{n}(e^{it}).$$
If we are lucky enough and $$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k(f)e^{ikt}$$ converges uniformly, then the limit will belong to $A(D)$. But this is not always the case. So, I was wondering if $A(D)$ is a topological complement of $C(T)$. I think the answer is negative. Any ideas?

Also, are there any sufficient coditions except from the absolute convergence of the Fourier series of $f$, in order for the sequences $g_{n},h_{n}$ to converge uniformly?

Comment: $A(D)$ is not complemented in $C(T)$, as you already suspected: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplementedSubspace.html